# Smooth update of DOM tree in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am looking for a good solution of migrating the DOM tree in a smooth way. Let's imagine a DOM tree like this which shows a list of books:

```
<div class="books">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="title">Book 1</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="title">Book 2</div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

This list should be updated by a new version which I generate from server's input:

```
<div class="books">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="title">This is a new Book</div>
      ...
    </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="title">Another book</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="book">
    <div class="title">Book 2</div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I could just replace the whole structure by the new one. This causes a big flicker on the screen, which I would like to avoid. My aim is it to iterate through the element in a recursive way and depending on a found difference between the old an the new structure I will only update the altered elements.

This algorithm isn't very simple to implement in a robust way. That's why I am asking, if anybody knows a library, which can achieve this.

Comment: So if the new structure has no difference from the first one, except the text in `.title` blocks, just replace that text. Or do I miss something?

Comment: What exactly is the input and logic to use on the input here?

Comment: You should consider having the server just send the changed/added entries instead of everything. Not only does that allow you to update just the changes, it also speeds up the process, because not the whole list needs to be sent each time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) is a library that does handle what you're talking about doing. The library maintains a virtual copy of the DOM, and when changes are made which would require revising the page the real and virtual DOMs are diffed, with only the necessary changes being made to the page.

Frankly though, React seems like overkill unless you decide you really want a serious heavyweight library handling your model-view.

If you're having trouble with DOM-change stutter, you could consider wrapping your updating calls with `requestAnimationFrame` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)).

As for implementing a diff algorithm on your own, sounds like it could be a really fun exercise!

Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame
http://facebook.github.io/react/